# Does envoy proxy support whitelist

Tags: nginx, whitelist

I used envoy proxy as reverse proxy, and is envoy proxy support limiting access to certain client addresses like nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, it implements IP whitelisting within a much broader concept, [RBAC](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/api-v2/config/rbac/v2alpha/rbac.proto#envoy-api-field-config-rbac-v2alpha-principal-source-ip).